# Overlapping CI, not the typical overlap scenario

Tags: statistical-significance

Here is my question on behavior A. What does it mean when the CI of one subgroup completely envelops the CI of the other subgroup? I performed a 2 sided t-test and this shows a statistically significant at p<0.05 but the CI of one group completely envelops the other (see results below).

Behavior A is exhibited in 34.4% (95%CI: 30.7-38.4) of non-Hispanic blacks
Behavior A is exhibited in 36.0% (95%CI: 34.6-37.3) of non-Hispanic whites

Does the statistical test make sense?

Comment: How many Blacks and how many Whites do you have?

Comment: It seems likely there's an error somewhere, since your A interval is not that close to symmetric -- it should either be symmetric (via a z interval) or very close to symmetric (any of a number of binomial-based confidence intervals), given the width of the interval, which suggests a sample size up around 580. Is this from a paper?

Comment: These are results from complex sample survey, such as those from the National Health Interview Survey, hence why the SE are not symetrical.

Answer (score 0):

With the data you have shared, it just means that behavior A is observed in 34.4% of non-Hispanic blacks and 36% non-Hispanic whites... but they actually do not overlap since you are describing the same behavior observed in 2 different subgroups of the studied population. So, in proportion, behavior A is observed in the same order of magnitude in both subgroups.